# Why do I get this error when installing Laravel on the command line with Composer?

Tags: php, laravel, cmd, composer-php, laravel-6

```
C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel>composer create-project laravel/laravel taamirgah "6.*"
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./taamirgah"
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Installing laravel/laravel (v6.20.1)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v6.20.1): Extracting archive
Created project in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 93 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking doctrine/inflector (2.0.4)
  - Locking doctrine/instantiator (1.4.1)
  - Locking doctrine/lexer (1.2.3)
  - Locking dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.3.1)
  - Locking egulias/email-validator (2.1.25)
  - Locking facade/flare-client-php (1.9.1)
  - Locking facade/ignition (1.18.1)
  - Locking facade/ignition-contracts (1.0.2)
  - Locking fakerphp/faker (v1.19.0)
  - Locking fideloper/proxy (4.4.1)
  - Locking filp/whoops (2.14.5)
  - Locking hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1)
  - Locking laravel/framework (v6.20.44)
  - Locking laravel/tinker (v2.7.2)
  - Locking league/commonmark (1.6.7)
  - Locking league/flysystem (1.1.9)
  - Locking league/mime-type-detection (1.11.0)
  - Locking mockery/mockery (1.5.0)
  - Locking monolog/monolog (2.7.0)
  - Locking myclabs/deep-copy (1.11.0)
  - Locking nesbot/carbon (2.59.1)
  - Locking nikic/php-parser (v4.14.0)
  - Locking nunomaduro/collision (v3.2.0)
  - Locking opis/closure (3.6.3)
  - Locking paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.100)
  - Locking phar-io/manifest (2.0.3)
  - Locking phar-io/version (3.2.1)
  - Locking php-parallel-lint/php-console-color (v0.3)
  - Locking php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter (v0.5)
  - Locking phpdocumentor/reflection-common (2.2.0)
  - Locking phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (5.3.0)
  - Locking phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.6.1)
  - Locking phpoption/phpoption (1.8.1)
  - Locking phpspec/prophecy (v1.15.0)
  - Locking phpunit/php-code-coverage (9.2.15)
  - Locking phpunit/php-file-iterator (3.0.6)
  - Locking phpunit/php-invoker (3.1.1)
  - Locking phpunit/php-text-template (2.0.4)
  - Locking phpunit/php-timer (5.0.3)
  - Locking phpunit/phpunit (9.5.21)
  - Locking psr/container (1.1.2)
  - Locking psr/log (2.0.0)
  - Locking psr/simple-cache (1.0.1)
  - Locking psy/psysh (v0.11.6)
  - Locking ramsey/uuid (3.9.6)
  - Locking scrivo/highlight.php (v9.18.1.9)
  - Locking sebastian/cli-parser (1.0.1)
  - Locking sebastian/code-unit (1.0.8)
  - Locking sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (2.0.3)
  - Locking sebastian/comparator (4.0.6)
  - Locking sebastian/complexity (2.0.2)
  - Locking sebastian/diff (4.0.4)
  - Locking sebastian/environment (5.1.4)
  - Locking sebastian/exporter (4.0.4)
  - Locking sebastian/global-state (5.0.5)
  - Locking sebastian/lines-of-code (1.0.3)
  - Locking sebastian/object-enumerator (4.0.4)
  - Locking sebastian/object-reflector (2.0.4)
  - Locking sebastian/recursion-context (4.0.4)
  - Locking sebastian/resource-operations (3.0.3)
  - Locking sebastian/type (3.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/version (3.0.2)
  - Locking swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.3.0)
  - Locking symfony/console (v4.4.43)
  - Locking symfony/css-selector (v6.1.0)
  - Locking symfony/debug (v4.4.41)
  - Locking symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.1.1)
  - Locking symfony/error-handler (v4.4.41)
  - Locking symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.4.42)
  - Locking symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v1.1.13)
  - Locking symfony/finder (v4.4.41)
  - Locking symfony/http-client-contracts (v2.5.2)
  - Locking symfony/http-foundation (v4.4.43)
  - Locking symfony/http-kernel (v4.4.43)
  - Locking symfony/mime (v5.4.10)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.26.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.26.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.26.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.26.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.26.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.26.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.26.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.26.0)
  - Locking symfony/process (v4.4.41)
  - Locking symfony/routing (v4.4.41)
  - Locking symfony/service-contracts (v2.5.2)
  - Locking symfony/translation (v4.4.41)
  - Locking symfony/translation-contracts (v2.5.2)
  - Locking symfony/var-dumper (v4.4.42)
  - Locking theseer/tokenizer (1.2.1)
  - Locking tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.4)
  - Locking vlucas/phpdotenv (v3.6.10)
  - Locking webmozart/assert (1.11.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 93 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading symfony/service-contracts (v2.5.2)
  - Downloading symfony/console (v4.4.43)
  - Downloading monolog/monolog (2.7.0)
  - Downloading symfony/mime (v5.4.10)
  - Downloading symfony/http-foundation (v4.4.43)
  - Downloading symfony/http-client-contracts (v2.5.2)
  - Downloading symfony/http-kernel (v4.4.43)
  - Downloading symfony/translation-contracts (v2.5.2)
  - Downloading nesbot/carbon (2.59.1)
  - Downloading psy/psysh (v0.11.6)
  - Downloading phpunit/phpunit (9.5.21)
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (2.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.3.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.26.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.26.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.26.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v4.4.42): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.1.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/container (1.1.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.5.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.26.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/console (v4.4.43): Extracting archive
  - Installing scrivo/highlight.php (v9.18.1.9): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/log (2.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing monolog/monolog (2.7.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.26.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.8.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v3.6.10): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v6.1.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/routing (v4.4.41): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.4.41): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.26.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.26.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/mime (v5.4.10): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.4.43): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/http-client-contracts (v2.5.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v1.1.13): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.4.42): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/debug (v4.4.41): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/error-handler (v4.4.41): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.4.43): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/finder (v4.4.41): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.26.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.25): Extracting archive
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.3.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.100): Extracting archive
  - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.9.6): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing opis/closure (3.6.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v2.5.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/translation (v4.4.41): Extracting archive
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (2.59.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/mime-type-detection (1.11.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.1.9): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/commonmark (1.6.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/framework (v6.20.44): Extracting archive
  - Installing filp/whoops (2.14.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing facade/ignition-contracts (1.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing facade/flare-client-php (1.9.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing facade/ignition (1.18.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing fakerphp/faker (v1.19.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing fideloper/proxy (4.4.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.14.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.11.6): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/tinker (v2.7.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing mockery/mockery (1.5.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing php-parallel-lint/php-console-color (v0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter (v0.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing nunomaduro/collision (v3.2.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.11.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (2.2.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.6.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (5.3.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/version (3.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/type (3.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/resource-operations (3.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (4.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/object-reflector (2.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/object-enumerator (4.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/global-state (5.0.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (4.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/environment (5.1.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/diff (4.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (4.0.6): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/code-unit (1.0.8): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/cli-parser (1.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (5.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (2.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-invoker (3.1.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (3.0.6): Extracting archive
  - Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.2.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/lines-of-code (1.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/complexity (2.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (2.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (9.2.15): Extracting archive
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.4.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.15.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phar-io/version (3.2.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phar-io/manifest (2.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.11.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (9.5.21): Extracting archive
76 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1231
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1242
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1254
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1267
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 1231

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 1242

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 1254

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 1267

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Config\Repository.php on line 141

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Config\Repository.php on line 152

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Config\Repository.php on line 164

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Config\Repository.php on line 175

In Collection.php line 11:

  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExi
  sts($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWill
  Change] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\
  vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:1277
  Stack trace:
  #0 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php(11):
  Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'C:\\Users\\baran-...', 1
  277)
  #1 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): include('C:\\Users\\baran-...'
  )
  #2 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile(
  'C:\\Users\\baran-...')
  #3 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(109): Co
  mposer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')
  #4 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.p
  hp(130): collect(Array)
  #5 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.p
  hp(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
  #6 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.p
  hp(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
  #7 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.p
  hp(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('aliases')
  #8 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\Registe
  rFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
  #9 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(2
  19): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
  #10 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.p
  hp(320): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
  #11 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.p
  hp(129): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
  #12 C:\Users\baran-pc\Desktop\Laravel\taamirgah\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Sy
  mfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
  #13 {main}


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a wrong version of PHP installed. L6 requires PHP >= 7.2.5, you most likely have 8 installed

Comment: You need to update your version of composer. `composer self-update`

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be nice if you would not just throw your code and error message at us, but also write a few sentences about what you want to achieve and what you tried so far. Also, please make use of the formatting possibilities we provide also for your logs.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting this error?

The composer configuration you have has configured a post-dump-autoload script, namely `Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump`, which is incompatible with the PHP version you're using on the commandline (and Composer runs with).

That Composer script in combination with it's own `laravel/laravel/composer.json` configuration is of little quality and does not check its requirements before actionable use. Therefore you see a long trail of PHP error messages (diagnostic messages) which may be surprisingly noisy and therefore you're not able to spot this otherwise obvious issue of a PHP version mismatch.

Meet the requirements of your composer.json configuration and then you're fine to go. And perhaps you should report the issue upstream if you're a user of `laravel/laravel`, it seems it could benefit from some users feedback.

At the end of the day this is just a PHP notice, see the [upgrade notices for PHP 8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.php) in this case if you're interested in more context.